# *imaxima* error: "Not enough arguments for format string"

Tags: maxima

After I start `imaxima` and get a prompt, I try typing `1 + 1` or any other expression and evaluate. Then I get the error:

```
  enter code hereDebugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Not enough arguments for format string")
  format("\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}")
  apply(format "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" nil)
  (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n"))
  (if label (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n")) (concat (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) "\\begin{math} \\displaystyle " str (format " \\end{math}\n")))
  (insert (format "\\documentclass[%dpt,leqno]{article}\n" imaxima-pt-size) "\n% mylatex\n" (format "\\setlength{\\textwidth}{%dmm}\n" (round (/ (imaxima-get-window-width) imaxima-scale-factor))) (if linear (concat "\\renewcommand{\\ifrac}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracd}[2]{#1/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracn}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/#2}" "\\renewcommand{\\isubscript}[2]{\\mathrm{subscript}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\iexpt}[2]{\\mathrm{expt}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\isqrt}[1]{\\left(#1\\right)^{1/2}}\n") "") "\\begin{document}\n" (apply (quote format) "\\pagecolor[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb (imaxima-get-bg-color))) "\\pagestyle{empty}\n" (format "\\begin{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-label-color)) "\\tt" (if label (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n")) (concat (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) "\\begin{math} \\displaystyle " str (format " \\end{math}\n"))) (format "\\end{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) "\\end{document}")
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (insert (format "\\documentclass[%dpt,leqno]{article}\n" imaxima-pt-size) "\n% mylatex\n" (format "\\setlength{\\textwidth}{%dmm}\n" (round (/ (imaxima-get-window-width) imaxima-scale-factor))) (if linear (concat "\\renewcommand{\\ifrac}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracd}[2]{#1/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracn}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/#2}" "\\renewcommand{\\isubscript}[2]{\\mathrm{subscript}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\iexpt}[2]{\\mathrm{expt}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\isqrt}[1]{\\left(#1\\right)^{1/2}}\n") "") "\\begin{document}\n" (apply (quote format) "\\pagecolor[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb (imaxima-get-bg-color))) "\\pagestyle{empty}\n" (format "\\begin{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-label-color)) "\\tt" (if label (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n")) (concat (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) "\\begin{math} \\displaystyle " str (format " \\end{math}\n"))) (format "\\end{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) "\\end{document}"))
  (prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (insert (format "\\documentclass[%dpt,leqno]{article}\n" imaxima-pt-size) "\n% mylatex\n" (format "\\setlength{\\textwidth}{%dmm}\n" (round (/ (imaxima-get-window-width) imaxima-scale-factor))) (if linear (concat "\\renewcommand{\\ifrac}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracd}[2]{#1/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracn}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/#2}" "\\renewcommand{\\isubscript}[2]{\\mathrm{subscript}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\iexpt}[2]{\\mathrm{expt}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\isqrt}[1]{\\left(#1\\right)^{1/2}}\n") "") "\\begin{document}\n" (apply (quote format) "\\pagecolor[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb (imaxima-get-bg-color))) "\\pagestyle{empty}\n" (format "\\begin{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-label-color)) "\\tt" (if label (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n")) (concat (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) "\\begin{math} \\displaystyle " str (format " \\end{math}\n"))) (format "\\end{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) "\\end{document}")) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (write-region nil nil temp-file nil 0)))
  (unwind-protect (prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (insert (format "\\documentclass[%dpt,leqno]{article}\n" imaxima-pt-size) "\n% mylatex\n" (format "\\setlength{\\textwidth}{%dmm}\n" (round (/ (imaxima-get-window-width) imaxima-scale-factor))) (if linear (concat "\\renewcommand{\\ifrac}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracd}[2]{#1/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracn}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/#2}" "\\renewcommand{\\isubscript}[2]{\\mathrm{subscript}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\iexpt}[2]{\\mathrm{expt}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\isqrt}[1]{\\left(#1\\right)^{1/2}}\n") "") "\\begin{document}\n" (apply (quote format) "\\pagecolor[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb (imaxima-get-bg-color))) "\\pagestyle{empty}\n" (format "\\begin{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-label-color)) "\\tt" (if label (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n")) (concat (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)) "\\begin{math} \\displaystyle " str (format " \\end{math}\n"))) (format "\\end{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) "\\end{document}")) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (write-region nil nil temp-file nil 0))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))
  (let ((temp-file filename) (temp-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name " *temp file*")))) (unwind-protect (prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (insert (format "\\documentclass[%dpt,leqno]{article}\n" imaxima-pt-size) "\n% mylatex\n" (format "\\setlength{\\textwidth}{%dmm}\n" (round (/ ... imaxima-scale-factor))) (if linear (concat "\\renewcommand{\\ifrac}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracd}[2]{#1/\\left(#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\ifracn}[2]{\\left(#1\\right)/#2}" "\\renewcommand{\\isubscript}[2]{\\mathrm{subscript}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\iexpt}[2]{\\mathrm{expt}\\left(#1,#2\\right)}" "\\renewcommand{\\isqrt}[1]{\\left(#1\\right)^{1/2}}\n") "") "\\begin{document}\n" (apply (quote format) "\\pagecolor[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb (imaxima-get-bg-color))) "\\pagestyle{empty}\n" (format "\\begin{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) (apply (quote format) "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" (imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-label-color)) "\\tt" (if label (concat (format "\\begin{dmath}[number={%s}]\n" label) (apply ... "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" ...) str (format "\\end{dmath}\n")) (concat (apply ... "\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}" ...) "\\begin{math} \\displaystyle " str (format " \\end{math}\n"))) (format "\\end{%s}\n" imaxima-fnt-size) "\\end{document}")) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (write-region nil nil temp-file nil 0))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))
  imaxima-tex-to-dvi("2" "\\%o1" "/tmp/imaxima14593VaH/1.tex")
  (cond ((eql eps-or-latex (quote latex)) (if (string-match "\\(\\([^]*\\)\\)" str) (progn (setq label (match-string 2 str)) (setq str (replace-match "" t t str 1)))) (if no-label-p (setq label nil)) (imaxima-tex-to-dvi str label (concat filename ".tex")) (imaxima-dvi-to-ps filename)) ((eql eps-or-latex (quote eps)) (copy-file str psfilename) (setq label nil)))
  (let* ((filename (expand-file-name (number-to-string (setq imaxima-file-counter (1+ imaxima-file-counter))) imaxima-tmp-subdir)) (psfilename (concat filename ".ps")) (label "*")) (cond ((eql eps-or-latex (quote latex)) (if (string-match "\\(\\([^]*\\)\\)" str) (progn (setq label (match-string 2 str)) (setq str (replace-match "" t t str 1)))) (if no-label-p (setq label nil)) (imaxima-tex-to-dvi str label (concat filename ".tex")) (imaxima-dvi-to-ps filename)) ((eql eps-or-latex (quote eps)) (copy-file str psfilename) (setq label nil))) (if (not (file-exists-p psfilename)) (imaxima-latex-error str filename) (let* ((--cl-var-- (imaxima-extract-bb psfilename)) (bb (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (width (nth 1 --cl-var--)) (height (nth 2 --cl-var--))) (let ((ratio (/ (imaxima-get-window-width) (imaxima-bp-to-mm width)))) (if (< ratio 1.0) (progn (if (or ... ...) (let ... ...) (if imaxima-linearize-flag ...))))) (if (eq imaxima-image-type (quote postscript)) nil (imaxima-ps-to-image psfilename filename bb width height)) (cond (nil (if (eq system-type (quote windows-nt)) (progn (kill-process imaxima-gs-process) (imaxima-start-gs))) (xemacs-set-imagefile-properties filename imaxima-image-type str)) (t (propertize (concat "(" label ") " str) (quote display) (if (eq imaxima-image-type ...) (create-image psfilename ... nil :pt-width width :pt-height height :bounding-box bb :ascent ... :mask ...) (create-image filename imaxima-image-type nil :ascent ... :mask ...))))))))
  imaxima-make-image("\\%o12" latex)
  (setq image (imaxima-make-image match (quote latex)))
  (concat output (setq image (imaxima-make-image match (quote latex))))
  (setq output (concat output (setq image (imaxima-make-image match (quote latex)))))
  (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output)) image) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output (setq image (imaxima-make-image match (quote latex))))) (if (null main-output) (setq main-output image)))
  (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output)) image) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output (setq image (imaxima-make-image match (quote latex))))) (if (null main-output) (setq main-output image))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))
  (cond ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((iprompt (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output))) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output iprompt)) (cond ((and continuation main-output) (funcall (car continuation) main-output)) ((and continuation (null main-output)) (funcall (car continuation) "")))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output)) image) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output (setq image (imaxima-make-image match ...)))) (if (null main-output) (setq main-output image))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output))) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output (imaxima-make-image match (quote latex))))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) (t (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output))) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output match))) (message "Unexpected error encountered in imaxima-filter"))))
  (let ((1stchar (substring imaxima-output 0 1))) (cond ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((iprompt (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output))) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output iprompt)) (cond ((and continuation main-output) (funcall ... main-output)) ((and continuation ...) (funcall ... "")))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output)) image) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output (setq image ...))) (if (null main-output) (setq main-output image))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output))) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output (imaxima-make-image match ...)))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) (t (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match (match-string 1 imaxima-output)) (rest (match-string 2 imaxima-output))) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output match))) (message "Unexpected error encountered in imaxima-filter")))))
  (while (not (string= imaxima-output "")) (let ((1stchar (substring imaxima-output 0 1))) (cond ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((iprompt ...) (rest ...)) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output iprompt)) (cond (... ...) (... ...))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match ...) (rest ...) image) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output ...)) (if (null main-output) (setq main-output image))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match ...) (rest ...)) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output ...))) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) (t (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ((match ...) (rest ...)) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output (concat output match))) (message "Unexpected error encountered in imaxima-filter"))))))
  (let ((lastchar (aref str (1- len))) (output "")) (if (and (char-equal lastchar 10) (> len 1)) (progn (setq lastchar (aref str (- len 2))))) (message "Processing Maxima output...") (while (not (string= imaxima-output "")) (let ((1stchar (substring imaxima-output 0 1))) (cond ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let (... ...) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output ...) (cond ... ...)) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let (... ... image) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output ...) (if ... ...)) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let (... ...) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output ...)) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))) (t (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let (... ...) (setq imaxima-output rest) (setq output ...)) (message "Unexpected error encountered in imaxima-filter")))))) (message "Processing Maxima output...done") (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))
  (if (zerop len) (progn (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) "")) (setq imaxima-output (concat imaxima-output str)) (let ((lastchar (aref str (1- len))) (output "")) (if (and (char-equal lastchar 10) (> len 1)) (progn (setq lastchar (aref str (- len 2))))) (message "Processing Maxima output...") (while (not (string= imaxima-output "")) (let ((1stchar (substring imaxima-output 0 1))) (cond ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ... ... ... ...) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw ... output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ... ... ... ...) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw ... output))) ((string= 1stchar "") (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ... ... ...) (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw ... output))) (t (if (string-match "\\([^]*\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)" imaxima-output) (let ... ... ...) (message "Unexpected error encountered in imaxima-filter")))))) (message "Processing Maxima output...done") (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output)))
  (let* ((len (length str)) main-output) (if (zerop len) (progn (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) "")) (setq imaxima-output (concat imaxima-output str)) (let ((lastchar (aref str (1- len))) (output "")) (if (and (char-equal lastchar 10) (> len 1)) (progn (setq lastchar (aref str (- len 2))))) (message "Processing Maxima output...") (while (not (string= imaxima-output "")) (let ((1stchar (substring imaxima-output 0 1))) (cond ((string= 1stchar "") (if ... ... ... ...)) ((string= 1stchar "") (if ... ... ... ...)) ((string= 1stchar "") (if ... ... ... ...)) (t (if ... ... ...))))) (message "Processing Maxima output...done") (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output))))
  (catch (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) (if imaxima-filter-running (progn (setq imaxima-output (concat imaxima-output str)) (debug-imaxima-filter "reenter") (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) ""))) (setq imaxima-filter-running t) (debug-imaxima-filter str) (let* ((len (length str)) main-output) (if (zerop len) (progn (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) "")) (setq imaxima-output (concat imaxima-output str)) (let ((lastchar (aref str (1- len))) (output "")) (if (and (char-equal lastchar 10) (> len 1)) (progn (setq lastchar (aref str ...)))) (message "Processing Maxima output...") (while (not (string= imaxima-output "")) (let ((1stchar ...)) (cond (... ...) (... ...) (... ...) (t ...)))) (message "Processing Maxima output...done") (setq imaxima-filter-running nil) (throw (quote --cl-block-imaxima-filter--) output)))))
  imaxima-filter("\n\\%o12\n(%i2) ")
  comint-output-filter(#<process imaxima> "\n\\%o12\n(%i2) ")
```

When I kill the buffer I see:

> Process imaxima hangup

It was working in the past, but I do remember encountering this error before. How might I resolve it?

Comment: According to the stacktrace, `(imaxima-color-to-rgb imaxima-equation-color)` is returning `nil` instead of a list of 3 floats. Maybe because `imaxima-equation-color` is `nil`?

Comment: apparently `imaxima-equation-color` was set as `#333333` but then got redefined somehow to `undefined-fg`.

Answer (score 2):

`format` is being called with only one argument, the format string. But the format-string argument has three `%` constructs, meaning that `format` expects three additional arguments, whose values are to be used by those `%` constructs.

The offending code, which calls `format` incorrectly, is apparently in function `imaxima-tex-to-dvi` or in some function that it calls.  Check the source code.

You can also use `M-x debug-on-entry imaxima-tex-to-dvi` and then step through the debugger using `d`, to see exactly where the problem is.